# Assets "count" variable

Tags: global-variables

I looked through the docs and wasn't able to find a count variable to see what file you are in using a field tag. For example, I want to detect when the first file is being looped though my custom field.

{custom_field}
    {if count == 0}foo{/if}
    bar
{/custom_field}

Comment: Whilst there doesn't appear to be a count, the docs make reference to EE native count working, have you tried placing count in your tags ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The count variable is 1-indexed so you need to do {if count == 1}{/if} to get the first in a loop.